# best practices for a small php web application

Tags: php, web-applications

i'm going create a very small web application for my team, and it is fairly specific -- list json files and edit them online. Using a framework like CI wouldn't justify, but I need to make it to be flexible, and easily maintainable by other programmers. I've done several one-page apps before and done it using  `switch`. Not sure if this is correct, and i think there are better ways to do this.

EDIT: I am trying to do away from frameworks, really keeping it simple. or a minimum of a 3 file framework may do.

Comment: [KissMVC](http://kissmvc.com/) is a really simple MVC framework that I have used before for projects like this.

Comment: what's are the best practices for creating small php web apps, without using frameworks as much as possible

Comment: @LouisBataillard , that is not MVC , or even a framework.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a thing as [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/), micro-framework from Sensio Labs?